# Drawing a filled Polygon with libgdx at the right position

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, polygon, lighting

I am currently implementing a lighting system to my game.
My light class calculates a polygon for my light to be visible in.
All I need to do now is to cut my light texture in this shape.

I am trying to archieve this by creating a polygonRegion and drawing it to a polygonSpriteBatch.

Thats what I do at the moment:

```
    polygonRegion = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(light), vertices,
            new EarClippingTriangulator().computeTriangles(vertices).toArray());
```

and in the drawing step:

```
    polygonSpriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(lightHandler.tiledTest.cameraHandler.camera.combined);
    polygonSpriteBatch.begin();
    polygonSpriteBatch.draw(polygonRegion, 0, 0);
    polygonSpriteBatch.end();
```

The polygon is actually working fine and as intended but problem is currently, that the actual light texture doesn´t seem to show up at my actual light´s coords in the center of the polygon, but on the lower left corner of the map. So my light polygon is actually black until I place it in that very corner.

Here is a screen with some light sources placed on the map. Please ignore the green and yellow lines. Those are for debugging the polygon.

https://1drv.ms/i/s!AgucvuUdePpwhZg7rqn6pk7cYktf1A

This is how i want my light polygon to actually look:

https://1drv.ms/i/s!AgucvuUdePpwhZg6Y8Y2JiKplGm6ig

I hope you can help me with this problem!

Apologies for any mistakes I did with this post.. it´s my first one here!

Comment: Nobody got an idea?

Comment: Yeah kind of. I want the rectangle to change its shape if there is something in the way of the light. I already do compute the required polygon and it works. I only need to find a way to apply it on the texture.